# Extract the three words following the keywords

Tags: r, regex

This regular expression written in R code extracts both the keywords and the words following them:

```r
regex <- paste0("(?i)\\b", keywords, "\\b\\s+(\\w+\\s+){0,2}(?!\\b", keywords, "\\b)\\w+")
```

How can I modify it so that it only extracts the three words following the keywords, excluding the keywords themselves?  For example, if the keyword in the sentence "the sun is beautiful" is "sun", then I would want to extract "is beautiful":

```r
sentences <- "the sun is beautiful"
keywords <- "sun"
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a reproducible example of your data?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
library(stringr)
keyword <- "sun"
sentence <- "the sun is beautiful"
regex <- paste0(keyword, "((\\s\\w+){1,3})")
str_match(sentence, regex)[2]
```

I hope that helps :)

**---- Edit: ----**

In case you have multiple keywords and multiple occurances, try this:

```
library(stringr)
sentence <- "the sun is beautiful today. the sun shines really bright in NY"
keywords <- c("really", "sun")
regex <- paste0(keywords, "((\\s\\w+){1,3})")
unlist(mapply(rbind.data.frame, str_match_all(sentence, regex))[2, ])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! could you adapt the code to a sentence list: chr [1:782]? Thanks again

Comment: You could just use a loop. The list is relatively small, so you short be fine performancewise.